# How do I effectively portray multiple characters in conversation?

Tags: gm-techniques, roleplaying

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you handle verbal exchanges between NPCs without taking the PCs out of the spotlight?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9880/how-do-you-handle-verbal-exchanges-between-npcs-without-taking-the-pcs-out-of-the)

You should be familiar with this set up:  All the characters are at a party with a plethora of NPCs.  The NPCs all talk to each other and some will include the character, some will not.  *How do you effectively role play a conversation between two (or more) NPCs that the characters may or may not be interacting with?* How do you keep clear which character is speaking?  How do you make sure that the conversation feels like a real one and not like one person playing both roles?